# Is there a way to load previous message on web version of WeChat?

Tags: wechat

I am using WeChat to communicate with my customer from mainland China. WeChat has a web version for better input and reading on PC. It is very much like the web version of WhatsApp, except that it does not load previous messages.

The problem is that I usually read the message on a phone first, and only open the web version if I need to reply using PC. (e.g. a long reply or a reply that requires screenshot of PC screen). As the question has already been read on the phone, it is omitted on the web version. It feels odd that the question is not at the top of the screen.

Is there a way to make WeChat load previous message?

<sub>Only messages that are stored on phone would be enough.</sub>